# wso2 esb filter with xquery expression inside property

Tags: wso2-esb

I want to use this expression in WSO2 property mediator

```
sum(//datas//queryResponse[CODEAGENCE='01003']//NOMBER)
```

I have done this to count without apply filter

```
fn:sum($ctx:datas//*[local-name()='queryResponse']//*[local-name()='NOMBRE'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is unclear. Do you want to count sum of NOMBRE field, using xquery on a property, that contains XML? If so, here is a sample API. You can call it from POSTMAN or browser http://{YourWSO2SErver}:8280/Test/testSO_57326564

The result is {"sum":"340.0"} on sample data.

Please note, that the property "datas" has OM type.

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Test" context="/Test"> 
   <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/testSO_57326564">
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <datas xmlns="">
                  <queryResponse>
                     <CODEAGENCE>01003</CODEAGENCE>
                     <NOMBRE>100</NOMBRE>
                  </queryResponse>
                  <queryResponse>
                     <CODEAGENCE>01003</CODEAGENCE>
                     <NOMBRE>240</NOMBRE>
                  </queryResponse>
                  <queryResponse>
                     <CODEAGENCE>01002</CODEAGENCE>
                     <NOMBRE>10000000</NOMBRE>
                  </queryResponse>
               </datas>
            </format>
            <args/>
         </payloadFactory>
         <property name="datas" expression="$body/*[1]" type="OM" description="property must be an OM type"/>         
         <property name="sum" expression="fn:sum($ctx:datas//queryResponse[CODEAGENCE=01003]/NOMBRE)"/>
         <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>            {"sum":"$1"}            </format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('sum')"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```